# Issue Regarding GoogleMaps DistanceMatrixApi

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

There is a glitch in the GoogleMaps DistanceMatrixApi.
For the origin pin code B3H and destination pin code B3J with Travel Mode = DRIVING, the distance returned from the GoogleMaps DistanceMatrixApi is null.
There are also some other cases when  the origin pin code R4G and destination pin codes in (R3J , R2J, R3W, R3M)  with Travel Mode = DRIVING ,the distance returned from GoogleMaps DistanceMatrixApi is null.

Answer (score 0):

I have send the request according to your requirement and it is giving me result
also travel mode is driving by default for distance matrix api, By default, directions are calculated as driving directions.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=B3H&destinations=B3J&mode=driving&key=YOUR_API_KEY